# Using Vuetify how can I place a search bar over a carousel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, carousel, vue-component, vuetify.js

As the title says, I want to place a search bar functionality over a carousel and I'm trying to achieve this using `<v-autocomplete>` and `v-carousel>`.

Using the code snippets from the official `Vuetify` [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes), I have managed to have this:

```
<template>
    <v-layout
        justify-center
        app
    >
        <v-flex
            xs12
            sm6
        >
            <v-container
                fluid
                grid-list-md
            >
                <v-layout
                    row
                    wrap
                >
                    <!--Carousel-->
                    <v-flex xs6>
                        <v-carousel
                            hide-controls
                            hide-delimiters
                            height='200'
                            interval='2500'
                        >
                            <v-toolbar
                            dark
                            color="teal"
                            >
                                <v-toolbar-title>State selection</v-toolbar-title>
                                    <v-autocomplete
                                    v-model="select"
                                    :loading="loading"
                                    :items="items"
                                    :search-input.sync="search"
                                    cache-items
                                    dense
                                    hide-no-data
                                    hide-details
                                    label="What state are you from?"
                                    solo-inverted
                                    >
                                    </v-autocomplete>
                                    <v-btn icon>
                                    <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
                                    </v-btn>
                                </v-toolbar>
                            <v-carousel-item
                                v-for="(item,i) in items"
                                :key="i"
                                :src="item.src"
                            >
                            </v-carousel-item>
                        </v-carousel>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-container>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
    <!--I use selective imports. This might not be needed for you when trying to reproduce it -->
            import VContainer from "vuetify/lib/components/VGrid/VContainer";
            import VFlex from "vuetify/lib/components/VGrid/VFlex";
            import VLayout from "vuetify/lib/components/VGrid/VLayout";
            import VCard from "vuetify/lib/components/VCard/VCard";
            import VImg from "vuetify/lib/components/VImg/VImg";
            import VCarousel from "vuetify/lib/components/VCarousel/VCarousel";
            import VAutocomplete from "vuetify/lib/components/VAutocomplete/VAutocomplete";

            export default {
                name: "HomeContents",
                data: () => ({
                    loading: false,
                    items: [],
                    search: null,
                    select: null,
                    states: [
                        'Alabama',
                        'Alaska',
                        'American Samoa',
                        'Arizona',
                        'Arkansas',
                        'California',
                        'Colorado',
                        'Ohio',
                        'Oklahoma',
                        'Oregon',
                        'Washington',
                        'West Virginia',
                        'Wisconsin',
                        'Wyoming'
                    ]
                }),
                watch: {
                    search (val) {
                    val && val !== this.select && this.querySelections(val)
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    querySelections (v) {
                        this.loading = true
                        // Simulated ajax query
                        setTimeout(() => {
                        this.items = this.states.filter(e => {
                        return (e || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((v || '').toLowerCase()) > -1
                        })
                        this.loading = false
                        }, 500)
                    }
                },
                components: {
                    VContainer,
                    VFlex,
                    VLayout,
                    VCard,
                    VImg,
                    VCarousel,
                    VAutocomplete
                }
            }
        </script>
```

The problems I am facing are the following:

1. How can I lose the teal toolbar and have just one simple single line to use for searching, *that will be positioned in the center of the carousel*?
2. Whenever I *click* on the search bar, I see this: [object Object]. How do I get rid of this?
3. With my current implementation, every time I'm searching for a state I'm able to successfully find it but the problem is that the carousel background transition effect stops. So for example, If I search for "Oklahoma" I can see the result but the background carousel transition stops. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll tackle your questions as you've put them.

1: The teal color is specified in your declaration of v-toolbar.

```
<v-toolbar
  dark
  color="teal"
>
```

You can set this color to anything you want, rgb or hex, so if you want it to be transparent you could do this.

```
<v-toolbar
  dark
  color="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
>
```

To specify the position of the toolbar comes down to styling. You can adjust the default vuetify styles but for a single item like this the easiest way to set styling that will override the default is to use inline styling, like this:

```
<v-toolbar
  dark
  color="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
  style="position:absolute;top:75px;z-index:400;"
>
```

As you've set the height, you can position the toolbar to center it. The z-index may be necessary to place it above the carousel. In here you could also style the text color, width etc.

2: In your posted code the reason you are getting `[object Object]` is because the v-autocomplete is trying to iterate through 'items' which is empty. You have 'states'. Set items like this: `:items="states"` To get this working as expected I set it up like this:

```
<v-autocomplete
style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0)"
v-model="select"
:items="states"
:loading="isLoading"
:search-input.sync="search"
color="white"
hide-no-data
hide-selected
item-text="Description"
item-value="state"
label="States"
placeholder="Start typing to Search"
prepend-icon="mdi-database-search"
return-object
>
</v-autocomplete>
```

Which is straight from the vuetify docs.

3: I can't reproduce the carousel pausing, it continues throughout on mine.

Hope this helps somewhat.